# PHP getting error message when i try to register with php page in android

Tags: php, android

PFB code. DB connection is success but when try to register with register.php script in my android phone getting error page or getting please fill all values. I am not getting success. Kindly help. I am also using the URL register url in my java code as well `http://xxxx/Userregistration/register.php`.

register.php

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if ($name == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == '') {
        echo 'please fill all values';
    } else {

        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM KumbhaApp  WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'";
        $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $sql));

        if (isset($check)) {
            echo 'username or email already exist';
        } else {
            require_once('dbConnect.php');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO KumbhaApp (name,username,password,email) VALUES('$name','$username','$password','$email')";
        }
    }

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    } else {

        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo 'successfully registered';
        header('Location: securedpage.php');
    } else {
        echo 'oops! Please try again!';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: Whats the error? You are open to SQL injections. You also should be hashing your passwords. You can't `echo` and `header`, use one or the other. You also should `exit` after using `header`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `required`, it is `require.` Your code

```
required ("http://localhost:8080/UserRegistration/dbConnect.php");
       ^
```

is wrong.

Comment: I  modified my code but still shows me nothing . It is blank. I am using hostinger DB. The connection is success but the register.php shows error. I am editing it here